# History.replaceState() not working on Chrome (mobile browser)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

#### The situation

After a user registers on our website, they receive an e-mail with a link to our homepage with verification token. Once a user clicks on the link, enters the page and sees a welcome modal. The token is silently removed from the url and history without the page being refreshed. This avoids users triggering a "Token already verified" message when pressing the back button or refreshing the page. When the user closes the welcome modal, the page is also refreshed to log them in.

We do this using `history.replaceState({}, pageTitle, '/')`, which should be supported on all browsers according to [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).

#### The issue

All browsers on mobile and desktop follow this behavior, except Chrome on mobile, which completely ignores the function and leaves the token in the url. This means that when users close the welcome modal and the page refreshes to log them in, they see a "Token already verified" message.

I'm evading this by, instead of reloading the page, "redirecting" the user to the same url without the token after closing the welcome modal.

#### The question

Does Chrome browser on mobile support `history.replaceState()` and am I doing something wrong in my code or does Chrome not support this API on mobile?

Comment: What happens on chrome mobile when leave the title empty within ''?

Comment: @Jayr still gives me the same result unfortunately